# Exchange 2010 Send-As permissions powershell script

Tags: powershell, permissions, exchange-server

I am trying to get a list of users that have Send As permissions to a specific mailbox, the command works but I don't know why PowerShell shows the same user information multiple times so when I run the command I get the same user information 7 times or so, I would just like it to show it once for each user.

This is the command I run:

```
 Get-MailboxPermission -Identity "carmelita.alexanderl" | Get-ADPermission | Where {$_.ExtendedRights -like "*Send-As*" -and $_.User -notlike "*NT AUTHORITY\SELF*" -and $_.User -notlike "*Domain Admins*" `
 -and $_.User -notlike "*Enterprise Admins*" -and $_.User -notlike "*Adno*" -and $_.User -notlike "*Organization Management*" `
 -and $_.User -notlike "*Public Folder Management*" -and $_.User -notlike "*Exchange Servers*" -and $_.User -notlike "*bbadmin*" `
 -and $_.User -notlike "*NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM*" -and $_.User -notlike "*NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE*" -and $_.User -notlike "*NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM*" `
 -and $_.User -notlike "*PARACLOUD\Administrator*" -and $_.User -notlike "*PARACLOUD\Delegated Setup*" -and $_.User -notlike "*Exchange Trusted Subsystem*" `
 -and $_.User -notlike "*ASP\Administrator*" -and $_.User -notlike "*PARACLOUD\Administrator*"} | fl -property *
```

This is the output that I get:

```
 AccessRights        : {ExtendedRight}
 ExtendedRights      : {Send-As}
 ChildObjectTypes    : 
 InheritedObjectType : 
 Properties          : 
 Deny                : False
 InheritanceType     : All
 User                : ASP\carmelita.alexander
 Identity            : asp.com/Clients/LRM/Users/LRM/Carmelita Alexander LRM
 IsInherited         : False
 IsValid             : True
 ObjectState         : Unchanged

 AccessRights        : {ExtendedRight}
 ExtendedRights      : {Send-As}
 ChildObjectTypes    : 
 InheritedObjectType : 
 Properties          : 
 Deny                : False
 InheritanceType     : All
 User                : ASP\carmelita.alexander
 Identity            : asp.com/Clients/LRM/Users/LRM/Carmelita Alexander LRM
 IsInherited         : False
 IsValid             : True
 ObjectState         : Unchanged

 AccessRights        : {ExtendedRight}
 ExtendedRights      : {Send-As}
 ChildObjectTypes    : 
 InheritedObjectType : 
 Properties          : 
 Deny                : False
 InheritanceType     : All
 User                : ASP\carmelita.alexander
 Identity            : asp.com/Clients/LRM/Users/LRM/Carmelita Alexander LRM
 IsInherited         : False
 IsValid             : True
 ObjectState         : Unchanged

 AccessRights        : {ExtendedRight}
 ExtendedRights      : {Send-As}
 ChildObjectTypes    : 
 InheritedObjectType : 
 Properties          : 
 Deny                : False
 InheritanceType     : All
 User                : ASP\carmelita.alexander
 Identity            : asp.com/Clients/LRM/Users/LRM/Carmelita Alexander LRM
 IsInherited         : False
 IsValid             : True
 ObjectState         : Unchanged

 AccessRights        : {ExtendedRight}
 ExtendedRights      : {Send-As}
 ChildObjectTypes    : 
 InheritedObjectType : 
 Properties          : 
 Deny                : False
 InheritanceType     : All
 User                : ASP\carmelita.alexander
 Identity            : asp.com/Clients/LRM/Users/LRM/Carmelita Alexander LRM
 IsInherited         : False
 IsValid             : True
 ObjectState         : Unchanged

 AccessRights        : {ExtendedRight}
 ExtendedRights      : {Send-As}
 ChildObjectTypes    : 
 InheritedObjectType : 
 Properties          : 
 Deny                : False
 InheritanceType     : All
 User                : ASP\carmelita.alexander
 Identity            : asp.com/Clients/LRM/Users/LRM/Carmelita Alexander LRM
 IsInherited         : False
 IsValid             : True
 ObjectState         : Unchanged
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Any other suggestions to get Send As permissions through PowerShell?

Thanks

Comment: Your search is overly complicated, you can simplify it by doing the following get-mailbox %mailbox% | Get-ADPermission | where {$_.ExtendedRights -like "*Send-As*" -and $_.user -notmatch "nt auth|S-1-5|Self....."} | fl -property *, I would say it would be cleaner to use select instead of fl so Select Identity, User, ExtendedRights

Comment: Not sure why you would get multiple outputs for the same permissions, but that's not to say it's never happened to me before... Does this happen on all users or just a few. I would perhaps remove and re-add the permissions as see if this still happens.

Comment: @Nick Eagle it happens with all the users as well, like Administrator, NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM and so on, it looks like it stores repeated information.

Comment: Ok, its because your using Get-MailboxPermissions, Use get-mailbox... Get-MailboxPermissions will list all permissions, which you are then piping to a Get-ADPermissions. This means that all Listed MailboxPermissions are being piped into Get-ADPermissions and it is getting it for each of the entries

Comment: Which command shall I use then? I just want to see the users that have Send As permissions to a specific mailbox. I thought this was the only way of doing it.

Comment: Get-Mailbox | Get-ADPermissions

Comment: That is it, thanks Nick. I was so blind. But I've got to say that I still don't understand why Get-MailboxPermission produces repeated information. I would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: If you run Get-MailboxPermissions, this will list several entries for permissions that are valid against that user, you are then piping each of those entries into Get-ADPermissions, meaning that each of this entries from Get-MailboxPermissions is then ran against Get-ADPermissions... You can see this by just running the command by its self.

Comment: Thank you very much Nick